# Connecting to Synology Nas FileStation via Quickconnect webapi returning HTML loading page

Tags: flutter, authentication, httprequest, synology

I am developing a flutter application which needs to access to a Synology Nas where there are my files stored. Basically I need to add a file manager into my application to handle the documents.

The problem comes when I try to do https requests (first to login and get the sid and after to try to retrieve data) to the Synology.

I have my url such as `<QuickconnectId>.fr3.quickconnect.to/webapi/auth.cgi` where I do the http request for login, for example. I made sure to create the http request properly,using SYNO.API.Auth, several versions, method 'login', etc..

The result of that http request is a loading page:

```
<!doctype html> <html> <head> <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-131382946-3">**strong text**  etc...
```

I tried the http requests using Postman and directly in my application. All the results are the same, the loading page.

I am expecting to receive the SID after login to be able to handle my documents.

I found that Synology uses some redirection and might be provided in some headers, but I don't know how to proceed, any help?